# Transferring XML data to access table

Tags: xml, vb.net, ms-access

Hey I previously asked this question a few weeks ago and the feedback did help but I'm still struggling to transfer the contents of my XML file to an access table. The error with this code is: "input string is not in a correct format." Would you have any ideas to fix the issue?

```
-<XML>
-<cards>
<name>Majespecter Toad - Ogama</name>
<type>Pendulum Effect Monster</type>
<desc>When this card is Normal or Special Summoned: You can Set 1 "Majespecter" Spell/Trap Card directly from your Deck, but it cannot activate this turn. You can only use this effect of "Majespecter Toad - Ogama" once per turn. Cannot be targeted or destroyed </desc>
<race>Spellcaster</race>
<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/645794.jpg</image_url>
<atk>1300</atk>
<def>500</def>
<level>4</level>
</cards>

-<cards>
<name>Gladiator Beast Retiari</name>
<type>Effect Monster</type>
<desc>When this card is Special Summoned by the effect of a "Gladiator Beast" monster, you can remove from play 1 card from your opponent's Graveyard. At the end of the Battle Phase, if this card attacked or was attacked, you can return it to the Deck to Specia</desc>
<race>Aqua</race>
<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/612115.jpg</image_url>
<atk>1200</atk>
<def>800</def>
<level>3</level>
</cards>
```

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        conn = New OleDbConnection
        dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        Dim databasePath = "Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;"
        conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & databasePath
        Dim command As OleDbCommand
        Try

            Dim f As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("C:\Users\1964\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\YGO Access Test v10\bin\Debug\MyData.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())

            Dim ds As New DataSet
            ds.ReadXml(f)
            conn.Open()
            command = New OleDbCommand()

            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Dim name As String = row.Item("name").ToString
                Dim type As String = row.Item("type").ToString
                Dim desc As String = row.Item("desc").ToString
                Dim race As String = row.Item("race").ToString
                Dim image_url As String = row.Item("image_url").ToString
                Dim atk As String = row.Item("atk").ToString
                Dim def As String = row.Item("def").ToString
                Dim level As String = row.Item("level").ToString

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Convert.ToString(name))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Convert.ToString(type))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Convert.ToString(desc))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@race", Convert.ToString(race))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_url", Convert.ToString(image_url))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atk", Convert.ToInt32(atk))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@def", Convert.ToInt32(def))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", Convert.ToInt32(level))

                command.Connection = conn
                command.CommandText = "insert into [" & decknametxt.Text & "] (name, type, [desc], race, image_url, atk, def, [level]) values(@name, @type, @desc, @race, @image_url, @atk, @def, @level)"
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your sample is not well-formed XML. Try opening it in an XML editor that would point out the errors, such as Visual Studio.

Comment: Oh right would that make a difference? I thought the error identified above was the only one. I created it through VB

Comment: In addition, element names cannot start with XML (case insensitive).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XML actually looks like this

```
<XML>
<cards>
<name>Majespecter Toad - Ogama</name>
<type>Pendulum Effect Monster</type>
<desc>When this card is Normal or Special Summoned: You can Set 1 "Majespecter" Spell/Trap Card directly from your Deck, but it cannot activate this turn. You can only use this effect of "Majespecter Toad - Ogama" once per turn. Cannot be targeted or destroyed </desc>
<race>Spellcaster</race>
<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/645794.jpg</image_url>
<atk>1300</atk>
<def>500</def>
<level>4</level>
</cards>

<cards>
<name>Gladiator Beast Retiari</name>
<type>Effect Monster</type>
<desc>When this card is Special Summoned by the effect of a "Gladiator Beast" monster, you can remove from play 1 card from your opponent's Graveyard. At the end of the Battle Phase, if this card attacked or was attacked, you can return it to the Deck to Specia</desc>
<race>Aqua</race>
<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/612115.jpg</image_url>
<atk>1200</atk>
<def>800</def>
<level>3</level>
</cards>
</XML>
```

stored on the file system then there is no need for XmlReader. Simply supply the 1st ds.ReadXML arg with the file path.

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.ReadXml("c:\data\test.xml")

Using AccessConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\DATA\AccessDB.accdb")
    AccessConn.Open()
    For Each DtRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        Using Table1Cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE1 ([name],[type],[desc],[race],[image_url],[atk],[def],[level]) " &
                                                  "VALUES (@name,@type,@desc,@race,@image_url,@atk,@def,@level)", AccessConn)
            Table1Cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DtRow("Name"))
            Table1Cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DtRow("Type"))
            Table1Cmd.Parameters.Add("@desc", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DtRow("Desc"))
            Table1Cmd.Parameters.Add("@race", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DtRow("Race"))
            Table1Cmd.Parameters.Add("@image_url", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DtRow("image_url"))
            Table1Cmd.Parameters.Add("@atk", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DtRow("atk"))
            Table1Cmd.Parameters.Add("@def", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DtRow("def"))
            Table1Cmd.Parameters.Add("@level", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DtRow("level"))
            Table1Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Disclaimer* be sure to use the proper OledbTypes and corresponding value conversions, my example used all string.